# Kth smallest in stream of numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

We are given a stream of numbers and Q queries.
At each query, we are given a number k.
We need to find the kth smallest number at that point of the stream.
How to approach this problem?

total size of stream is < 10^5

1 < number < 10^9

I tried linked list but finding the right position is time-consuming and in array inserting is time-consuming.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

Comment: How many queries are there? Are the queries given after the entire stream is at hand, or are they given mid-stream as well? (e.g. 3 numbers are given, then follows a query, then the rest of the stream is given, followed by some more queries)

Comment: everything is given at the same time.we have to assume it is a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree). They are many different kind of search trees but all the common ones allow insertion in *O(log n)* and finding the k<sup>th</sup> element in *O(log n)* too.

If the stream is too long to keep all the numbers in memory and you also know an upper bound on *k*, you can prune the tree by only keeping a number of elements equal to the upper bound.

Comment: order statistic tree can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a max heap with size=k.

Put elements until the heap's size reaches to k. After then, put an element and pop the heap's root so you can keep the size=k. Removing(extracting) root makes sense because there are at least k elements smaller than the root value.

When you finished iterating the stream, the root of the heap will be the k-th smallest element. Because you're having smallest k elements in the heap and the root is the largest among them.

As the heap's size is k, time complexity is O(n lg k) which could a bit better than O(n lg n). And the implementation would be a way easy.

Comment: If *k* was fixed, I'd prefer this approach. Alas, `At each query, we are given a number k`.

Comment: Read the first comment in the question.